# Java Type Erasure Problem

Tags: java, generics, types, type-erasure

I've made an example to demonstrate my problem:

*Metrical.java*

```
public interface Metrical<T>
{
    double distance(T other);
}
```

*Widget.java*

```
public class Widget implements Metrical<Widget>
{
    private final double value;

    public Widget(double value) { this.value = value; }

    public double getValue() { return value; }

    public double distance(Widget other) { return Math.abs(getValue() - other.getValue()); }
}
```

*Pair.java*

```
public class Pair<T>
{
    private final double value;
    private final T object1, object2;

    public Pair(T object1, T object2, double value)
    {
        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getObject1() { return object1; }

    public T getObject2() { return object2; }

    public double getValue() { return value; }
}
```

*Algorithm.java*

```
import java.util.Set;

public class Algorithm<T extends Metrical<T>>
{
    public void compute(Set<T> objects)
    {

    }

    public void compute(Set<Pair<T>> pairs)
    {

    }
}
```

So, in *Algorithm.java*, *Set< Pair< T >>* is being seen as a *Set< T >* and thus I am having type erasure problems.  However, is there any way I can get away with something like this without naming the methods differently?  Both variants of the algorithm are meant to operate on *T*'s, but I need to allow for different arguments.  They compute the same thing, so in an effort to avoid confusion, I would rather not name them differently.  Is there any way to accommodate this?

Comment: Technically this is not an erasure problem. Overloading is done at compile time. Adding additional runtime type information would not help.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't.

You have to remember that someone could call your method with just a vanilla Set, in which case which one would be called?

That's why you can't do it. Just like you can't do:

```
interface A {
  void blah(Set set);
  void blah(Set<T> set);
}
```

Same problem.

The type information isn't available at runtime (ie type erasure).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the bad news is that you cannot do this:

```
public class Algorithm<T extends Metrical<T>> {
    public void compute(Set<T> objects) {
    }

    public void compute(Set<Pair<T>> pairs) {
    }
}
```

Due to erasure, both will erase to the same signature.  There is no way around this short of renaming one of the methods.

Comment: Renaming one of the methods might not be a bad idea anyway - since they'll both be doing (slightly) different things (I guess).

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, this is the major area where Java Generics falls down... there is just no good solution.

I've generally resorted to making a new class, with the interface as `Set<Pair<T>>`, but that wraps `Set<Pair<T>>`  (without extending it, which would cause the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article about type erasure which can be of your interest.
It gives the common widely known solution and also a tricky way to circumvent the problem.
I don't know if it will be relevant for you. Anyway, it contains some techniques which may be useful under certain circumstances.

See also: [Using TypeTokens to retrieve generic parameters](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Using_TypeTokens_to_retrieve_generic_parameters)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `public class Widget<K, P> implements Metrical<K extends Widget<P>>`.

`public double distance(Widget other) {}` becomes `public double distance(Widget<P> other) {}`